# Prove existence of the saddle point for a Lagrangian implies the strong duality holds

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In "Convex Optimization" of Boyd, a saddle-point $(v_0, x_0)$ for a Lagrangian L is the one that satisfies the below inequalities, with $v$ and $x$ as variables of the dual and primal problems respectively (assuming the primal problem does not have equality constraint),

$$L(v_0, x) <= L(v_0, x_0) <= L(v, x_0) \space | \space \forall (x,v) $$

The optimal values of the dual and primal problem can be represented as the two expressions repspectively,
$$
d^* = \sup_v \inf_x L(v,x) \\
p^* = \inf_x \sup_v L(v, x)
$$

Strong duality holds, if
$$ p^* = d^* $$

How to prove the existence of the saddle point implies the below equations?
$$ p^* = d^* = L(v_0, x_0) $$

Comment: I guess the inequalities are somehow opposite. They correspond to maximizing in $x$ and minimizing in $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(v_0, x_0)$ is a saddle point. Note that
\begin{align*}
\forall x, L(v_0, x) \le L(v_0, x_0) &\implies \sup_x L(v_0, x) = L(v_0, x_0) \\
&\implies \inf_v \sup_x L(v, x) \le L(v_0, x_0).
\end{align*}
Suppose the inequality is strict. Then there exists some $v_1$ such that
$$\sup_x L(v_1, x) < L(v_0, x_0).$$
But then,
$$L(v_0, x_0) \le L(v_1, x_0) \le \sup_x L(v_1, x) < L(v_0, x_0).$$
This is a contradiction, hence $p^* = L(v_0, x_0)$.

We can show the other equality similarly, or simply by replacing $L$ with $-L$, and swapping the roles of $v$ and $x$.